# UIScrollView not paging correct distance

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll-paging

I'm creating a very simple detail view that has a few pictures the user can page through at the top, with some details on the item name on the bottom. However my scrollview does not page to the correct place, as so:

[image]

My scrollview's frame & the frame of its subviews are set as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.pictures.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height / CGFloat(2))
    self.pictures.clipsToBounds = false
    let width = pictures.frame.width
    let height = pictures.frame.height



    /*

    let view1 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(pictures.frame.origin.x, 0, scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight))
    let view2 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(pictures.frame.origin.x + scrollViewWidth, 0, scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight))
    let view3 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(pictures.frame.origin.x + scrollViewWidth * 2, 0, scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight))
    let view4 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(pictures.frame.origin.x + scrollViewWidth * 3, 0, scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight))

    */

    for index in 0...2 {
        let frame = CGRectMake(width * CGFloat(index), 0, width, height)
        let view = UIView(frame: frame)
        views.append(view)
        pictures.addSubview(view)
    }

    views[0].backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    views[1].backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    views[2].backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()


    pictures.delegate = self
    pictures.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width * CGFloat(views.count), height)


}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could fit this? Am I implementing my scrollview incorrectly?

Comment: Have you considered using a `UICollectionView` instead of a `UIScrollView`?

Comment: how would I incorporate a slideshow-type interface with a UICollectionView?

Comment: `UICollectionView` is based on `UIScrollView` and therefore has `pagingEnabled` it can also scroll horizontally using it's flowlayout

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you trying to access `self.view.frame` in `viewDidLoad()` function. In the moment when it called views are not laid out properly yet. Frame of the view will be of size what you specified in storyboard, probably {0, 0, 600, 600}.

**Solution:** You may put your page-initializing code to `viewWillAppear`, or you may consider using Auto Layout instead of directly manipulating frames.

Comment: unfortunately moving the initialization code to viewWillAppear did not fix the issue, though that was a good guess :/

Comment: I'm avoiding autolayout cause the number of views to be scrolled through (and subsequently the scrollView's content size) will be determined by how many pictures are uploaded. Much of this is dynamic, so I decided to do it programatically

Comment: viewDidLoad should have the correct size of view, but agreed autoresize mask with flexible height, width and left margin should be used. viewWillAppear isn't a good place for layout code either.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add +20 in your width because in scrollView some space is available between two page. 
So add 20 it may solve your problem.